# Why would this Boostrap selector be used?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I was going through the main **boostrap.css** file and came across several uses of this selector:

```
.btn-group-vertical > .btn:first-child:not(:last-child) {}
```

So it's selecting an element that has the `.btn` class which is a first child (but also not a last child?) of an element with the class `.btn-group-vertical`

Why would there be a need for the chained `:not()` selector? I can't imagine a use case for this.

Comment: You'd really need to ask the Bootstrap devs why they included this to know why they used this selector and not something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use case would be if it's a single element in the group, wherein it's both the first and last child.

Comment: But then why wouldn't they use `:only-child`?

Comment: IE8 support, maybe?

Comment: I don't think so, I believe all three selectors have the same browser support:

Comment: It's the same number of characters. `:last-child` is older and more familiar. Dunno.

Comment: Also `:last-child` is not older, they were all defined in Selectors Level 3 specification.

Answer (score 1):

I opened an issue on Github and got a response from the creator himself (Mark Otto):

> :first-child and :last-child can apply to the same element if it's the
>   only child element. We do this to avoid overriding properties again
>   and again. If we did :only-child we'd have to write another selector
>   altogether.

Comment: So @isherwood's answer is correct then